# Doubt on the definition of a dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

I am studying control theory and I am focusing on dynamical system. In the introdution of the notes of my professor, it is defined a dynamical system as a system defined by three elements:

1. **time**
2. **a set of functions defined on the time interval, W**
3. **the behaviour of the system at the given time**

I have clear what are the **1.** and **3.**, but I really can't understand what he means by **W**. Since we are considering a dynamical system in the context of control thoery, I would guess that these are the inputs and the outputs, but what can they be in a general context?

For example, consider the **evoulution of a population**. This is clearly a dynamical system, and can be modeled as:

$\dot{x}(t)=cx(t)$

in this case, what is the set of function $W$ as specified in **2.**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a slight modification of your system:

$\frac{d}{dt} x(t)=u(t)x(t)$.

Now, I think you would be comfortable with $W=\{u\}$, right? Now consider that we additionally require $u$ to be continuous. Does this change $W$? You will now probably ask: "why should it?"

And now comes the trick: by the same logic, you will have to admit that requiring $u$ to be constant should not change $W$. Now set $u(t)=c$ and you are back at your original example.